No puedo resturar base de datos en postgres
Llevo algunas horas con este problema...
He intentando restaurar un backdrup de una base de datos que me pasaron sin obtener resultado. No me marca error pero nunca finaliza el proceso o bien se muestre que se esta ejecutando;
Probe con otra version ya que tengo la 16 y el respaldo era de la 12 haci que me pasaron uno de la misma version y nada


preguta primero como tomaron el respaldo ese, puede diferir a la hora de restaurarlo
